# Regarding the values that n and r can take in $\binom{n}{r}$

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am thinking what values can n and r take in the following notation,
$\binom{n}{r} = {n!\over r!(n-r)!}$ ?

I mean which one among the following is correct and why?

- $0≤r≤n$ where $r,n\in Z_0^+---------(1)$
- $0≤r≤n$ where $r,n\in Z^+---------(2)$
- $0<r≤n$ where $r,n\in Z_0^+---------(3)$
- $0<r≤n$ where $r,n\in Z^+---------(4)$

Furthermore, can you kindly say if $\binom{0}{0}$ exists. If it does exist, I can not find it holding a physical meaning even though we can obtain 1 by simplifying.

I would like to know which is correct for **nPr** from the above 4 connections I have written. 1, 2, 3 or 4 and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a bit more involved than you might expect.  To be perfectly clear... *what do you mean* by $\binom{n}{r}$?  Are you taking this as an answer to a purely combinatorial problem?  Are you taking this as an answer to a purely set-theoretical problem?  Are you taking this as an algebraic object?  For the most common uses, these three all give the same answers and results, however they vary in terms of nuance when it comes to giving non-integer inputs or negative inputs etc...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am a grade 12 students and we were taught that we can use this to find how many ways we can select r objects out of n objects without considering the order they are aligned. So I'd guess what I am working on are purely combinatorial problems.

Comment: There must be a typo in there -- (3) and (4) are word-for-word identical.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you for pointing out. I edited it!

Comment: Now they are just _logically_ the same, instead of _literally_ the same!

Comment: Take a look at this https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9502218.pdf also https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RomanCoefficient.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a combinatorial definition, one has that $\binom{n}{r}$ is the answer to the question of "*How many $r$-element subsets are there of an $n$-element set?*"

Under this definition and interpretation, one has that the question is invalid and makes no sense when $n$ is not a non-negative integer (*There do not exist any sets with $-2$ number of elements of $\pi$ number of elements, etc...*) and similarly makes no sense when $r$ is not a non-negative integer (*similarly there exist no subsets of size $-2$ or size $\pi$ etc...*)

As such, we either treat $\binom{n}{r}$ as being equal to zero or being undefined in the case that $n$ or $r$ is not a non-negative integer.

The counting question is perfectly valid from a syntactical standpoint when the values are  both non-negative integers.  Some of these will be easy to answer immediately as "*there are none*" for example the question of "*How many $5$ element subsets are there of a $2$-element set?*"  There are no five-element subsets of a two-element set so the answer here is zero.  The notation $\binom{2}{5}$ is perfectly valid in this case as notating the answer to this question and equals zero.

As to the question of $\binom{0}{0}$, *this is also a perfectly valid question*!  The question being "*How many zero-element subsets of a zero-element set exist?*"  The answer to this question... is *one*!  There is in fact a zero-element subset of a zero-element set... Recall that $\emptyset\subseteq \emptyset$ is true.  We have then $\binom{0}{0}=1$

We have for this interpretation the following results:

$\binom{n}{r}$ is

- $0$ or undefined (*depending on preference*) whenever $n$ or $r$ is not a non-negative integer
- $1$ when $r=0$ or $r=n$ and $n$ is a non-negative integer (*including when $n=0$*)
- $0$ when $r>n$ and both $n$ and $r$ are non-negative integers
- a positive integer when $0\leq r\leq n$ and $r$ and $n$ are both non-negative integers

---

There also exists a purely algebraic interpretation.  $\binom{n}{r}$ is the coefficient of the $X^r$ term in the expansion of $(1+X)^n$.  We have the binomial theorem, that for non-negative integer $n$ we have $(1+X)^n = \sum\limits_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}X^r$.  This is further generalized to complex $n$.  The generalized binomial theorem is for $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ and $|X|<1$ we have

$$(1+X)^\alpha = \sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{r}X^r$$

where here $\binom{\alpha}{r} = \dfrac{\alpha\frac{r}{~}}{r!}$ where $\alpha\frac{r}{~}=\underbrace{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\cdots(\alpha-r+1)}_{r~\text{terms in the product}}$ is the falling factorial.  Note that here we do not require anything of $\alpha$ but we do still require $r$ to be a non-negative integer.

The values now of things such as $\binom{2}{5}$ and $\binom{\pi}{2}$ which made little sense before now do make sense.  $\binom{2}{5}=\dfrac{2\cdot 1\cdot 0\cdot (-1)\cdot (-2)}{5!}=0$ and $\binom{\pi}{2}=\dfrac{\pi(\pi-1)}{2!}$

The generalized binomial coefficient gives the same results for all non-negative integers.  You still have the same identities such as Paschal's identity.  There are just now many more cases which give non-zero defined results.