# What is the meaning of ${2\choose1}$ in $\frac{dy}{dx} = {2\choose1}x$, ${2\choose1} = \frac{dy/dx}{x}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

What do we count here? What do we count with (2 choose 1) in this particular situation of taking the derivative of x^2? The ratio of the speed at the growth of the area of a square and the growth of its side. As in the "art of counting", why nCr appears in calculus? In the rate of change of the area of a growing square, what is being counted?

$y = x^2$

$y + dy = (x + dx)^2$

$y + dy = {2\choose0}x^2 + {2\choose1}xdx + {2\choose2}dx^2$

$dy = {2\choose1}xdx$

$dy/dx = {2\choose1}x$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = {2\choose1}x$

${2\choose1} = \frac{dy/dx}{x}$

I can see that we are choosing the two `x` sides and the little bit of `x`-s, in other words`dx`-s. And we multiply them everywhich way to get the areas of `dy`. As if they were in a set of {x,dx}. If this was a cube, we would choose three sides and three little bits, and multiplied those for calculating the little bit of growth in volume.

Expanding $(x+dx)^n$ We discard the infinitesimal bits, the second term of the expansion, $\binom{n}{1}x$, seems to remain as the derivative. I wonder if there is a combinatorics connection, if it can be seen on the graphs of functions, or in the arrangements of elements.

[image: fumbling attempts at understanding connection of derivative and counting]

[image: more thinking]

I think what I'm curious about is that `2C1 = something`, or `2C1 means ...`,  and it is the ratio of `(dy/dx)/x`, the 2C1 we use in arranging letters is this ratio. I don't see how. Maybe it shows that there are 2 sides of a square, and 2 little bits, and with x^3 it's three sides and three bits etc

[image: more fumbling]

Comment: As for the combinatorial argument, the binomial theorem has one. Count the number of ways to get $a^kb^{n-k}$ in the expansion of $(a+b)^n.$

Comment: @aqualubix `|{x•x, x•dx, dx•x, dx•dx}| = 4`
`x•dx + dx•x` *is* the derivative, the slope, the ratio `dy/dx`
`dy/dx = |{x•dx, dx•x}| • x`

Comment: (a little bit of y) to a (a little bit of x) is the product of the (number of ways to arrange {x,dx}) and (x)

Comment: This question needs significant work to be clear.  
A. Are you asking what does $(2 \over 1 )$ means?  See my next comment.
Where does $(x+dx)^n$ fit in?  Please elaborate how it's connected to the rest of the question.
What is the original function before you took the derivative?

Comment: $\binom{2}{1} = \frac{2!}{1! \cdot 1!} = \frac21$
This link includes the formula.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982474/regarding-the-values-that-n-and-r-can-take-in-binomnr

Comment: If $y=x^n$, $d^ky/dx^k=k!\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}$.

Comment: There’s something odd here.

Comment: I think the fourth line in the last picture should be "$=y+\binom{2}{1}x\;dx$".

Comment: Why do you close this question? I would love to clarify this question, and I added a ton of more info on it already, and in the link you suggested for clarifying the question it says that I will receive feedback and guidance in private to clarify the question. I didn't receive any feedback in private. Also no one addressed the question: what do we count with (2 choose 1) in this particular situation? As in the "art of counting", why nCr appears in calculus? In the rate of change of a growing square, what is being counted?

Comment: @nickalh thank you for your comment. I more or less understand the meaning of 2C1, I would like to know why we use it in taking the derivative of f(x)=x^2, what does it mean in an intuitive sense. I find it difficult to see what the ratio of (the ratio of the dy areas to the little bit of dx) to (the side x) means, and why this is equal to 2C1. Perhaps if there was a simple English translation to this, or a visualisation of some sort. I am interested in the grasping simple meaning of these abstract terms.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} x = 2x$

So $dy= 2x dx$

Upon integration we get,

$y= x^2 + \mathrm{constant \, of \, integration}$

Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Nice, I didn't see we can integrate `dy= 2x dx` back. I'm just learning all this. I am intrested in the role of (2 choose 1).

Answer (score 1):

It just means $^{n}C_{r}$ or normal combination formula which is $\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$.

Here it's $2$.

Comment: Thank you @Gwen!  Do you happen to know why we use this combination formula in calculus? In the derivative of a square or cube?

Comment: Isn't that the way of expanding using binomial theorem?

Comment: It's the binomial expansion theorem. $$(a+b)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}a^{k}b^{n-k}$$ if and only if $n≥1$

Comment: ${n\choose1} = \frac{!}{(−1)!1!} = \frac{dy/dx^{n-1}}{x}$ I wonder why this is the case.